# How to show google admob from 2 accounts?

Tags: ios, admob

I have an iOS app that integrated with Google Admob. Now I want to show admobs from two accounts. like 50% from one account and other 50% from another account. what is the most suitable way to do this?
Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 separate AdUnitIds and randomly choose one on app startup.